# 'this' keyword is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am newbie to react and  just trying to learn about state and component but iam getting some errors plz can anyone help me out

**my main app.js code is this**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Greet from './Comp'

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='App'>
    <Greet></Greet>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**and my comp.js code is this**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

class Greet extends Component (){
constructor(props){
    super(props)
        this.state = {
            message:'hello'
        }
    
}
   
   
    render(){
        return (
        <h1>hello {this.state.message}</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default Greet;
```

[image: it shows the following errors]

is their any problem with my webpack or my code?

Comment: wizard, did the below answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `()` from this line `class Greet extends Component ()`, So it would be like `class Greet extends Component`.